# Define a global variable in Vue with single file components

Tags: vue.js

I'm using [vue-sweetalert2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sweetalert2), and would like to define a variable that specifies the style of a popup which will be used in multiple component files. e.g.:

```
const swalWithBootstrapButtons = this.$swal.mixin({
  confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
  cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
  buttonsStyling: false,
})
```

Where and how can I define this such that it can be accessed from all components?

I tried setting `Vue.prototype.$swalWithBootstrapButtons` in my `main.js` but I can't figure out how properly reference `this.$swal`.

Comment: Have you tried with plugins ? If not, I would advise you to try it : [Plugins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get things working by creating a Plugin. When I get a chance I'll write up what I did to see if it was the "right way".